# Open HTML file stored outside the asset folder in a webview

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

Hi i am new to android development and have been searching everywhere on the internet for how to display simple html file on `webView`. Almost everybody is using the code:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

which works fine **ONLY** when the html file is inside the asset folder of the android app!. I am trying to do something that loads the html file from another drive and have searched everywhere to find this solution to no avail. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From another drive? Please give full path of html file.

Comment: What do you mean by "from another drive"?